Why is the data returned by WMI not same as the structrue in NDIS_OFFLOAD
I followd this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/udp-rsc-offload to query URO state with wmi
Using this script in windows powershell:
$NDIS_WMI_METHOD_HEADER_REVISION_1             = 1
$NDIS_WMI_OBJECT_TYPE_METHOD                   = 0x02
$NDIS_SIZEOF_WMI_METHOD_HEADER_REVISION_1      = 0xffff
function Get-NdisObjectHeader
{
param(
$revision = $NDIS_WMI_METHOD_HEADER_REVISION_1,
$type     = $NDIS_WMI_OBJECT_TYPE_METHOD,
$size     = $NDIS_SIZEOF_WMI_METHOD_HEADER_REVISION_1
)
$hdr = ([wmiclass]'root\wmi:MSNdis_ObjectHeader').CreateInstance()
$hdr.Revision      = $revision
$hdr.Type          = $type
$hdr.Size          = $size
return $hdr
}
function Get-NdisWmiHeader
{
param($timeout = 5)
$whdr = ([wmiclass]'root\wmi:MSNdis_WmiMethodHeader').CreateInstance()
$whdr.Header       = Get-NdisObjectHeader
$whdr.PortNumber   = 0
$whdr.NetLuid      = 0
$whdr.Padding      = 0
$whdr.RequestId    = 0
$whdr.Timeout      = $timeout
return $whdr
}
$whdr = Get-NdisWmiHeader
$r = Get-WmiObject -Class MSNdis_TcpOffloadCurrentConfig -Namespace "root\WMI"
$x=$r[3].WmiQueryCurrentOffloadConfig($whdr)

PS C:\Windows\System32> $x.Offload
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : MSNdis_WmiOffload
__SUPERCLASS     : MSNdis
__DYNASTY        : MSNdis
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 6
__DERIVATION     : {MSNdis}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
Checksum         : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
Flags            : 0
Header           : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
IPsecV1          : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
LsoV1            : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
LsoV2            : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject
PSComputerName   :

The result returned by wmi does not include the field UdpRsc in NDIS_OFFLOAD
typedef struct _NDIS_OFFLOAD {
  NDIS_OBJECT_HEADER                       Header;
  NDIS_TCP_IP_CHECKSUM_OFFLOAD             Checksum;
  NDIS_TCP_LARGE_SEND_OFFLOAD_V1           LsoV1;
  NDIS_IPSEC_OFFLOAD_V1                    IPsecV1;
  NDIS_TCP_LARGE_SEND_OFFLOAD_V2           LsoV2;
  ULONG                                    Flags;
  NDIS_IPSEC_OFFLOAD_V2                    IPsecV2;
  NDIS_TCP_RECV_SEG_COALESCE_OFFLOAD       Rsc;
  NDIS_ENCAPSULATED_PACKET_TASK_OFFLOAD    EncapsulatedPacketTaskOffloadGre;
  NDIS_ENCAPSULATED_PACKET_TASK_OFFLOAD_V2 EncapsulatedPacketTaskOffloadVxlan;
  UCHAR                                    EncapsulationTypes;
  NDIS_RFC6877_464XLAT_OFFLOAD             Rfc6877Xlat;
  NDIS_UDP_SEGMENTATION_OFFLOAD            UdpSegmentation;
  NDIS_UDP_RSC_OFFLOAD                     UdpRsc;
} NDIS_OFFLOAD, *PNDIS_OFFLOAD;

and looks like missing many fields, such IPsecV2,Rsc,EncapsulatedPacketTaskOffloadGre .
How can I get the udpRsc field and my windows os version is 24h2
